# Finding a function that satisfies the conditions of an integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int_a^b f(x) ~ dx = \frac{1}{\pi} $$

**Conditions:**

1. $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} $ ($a,b$ finite and rational)
2. $f(x)$ is not any composition of a trigonometric function, their inverse, hyperbolic function and their inverse. All the other functions, symbols etc, are welcome.

That's a riddle by itself - but knowing that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $ we can take it to be:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2x}{ \sqrt{ 6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}}}, ~~ a = 0, ~~b = 1$$

Thus:

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) ~ dx = \int_0^1\frac{2x}{ \sqrt{ 6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}}} dx = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ 6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}}} \int_0^1 2x ~ dx = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ 6 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}}} \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{6 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6}}} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

**Now, I add one more condition:**

3. $f(x)$ cannot be an infinite sum / use any finite or infinite sums in it, and the integral cannot be an 'approximation' - meaning that it has an answer just like the above, when we actually get to the value $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and not some value $t + O(1)$. Furthermore, $f$ is not a constant function and cannot have the number $\pi$ anywhere in the function. Other irrationals (e.g. $e$) are allowed

**Note:**
This is more of a 'fun' question, meaning that those conditions on $a,b$ still hold true, but the restriction on $f$ are vague, the only thing that is agreed on is no trig functions, and not using the $\pi$ constant, and the function should be 'finite' and not a long sum of any variable (not just $x$) meaning that the previous answer does not hold, because we sum over a variable ($k$). In short, I want a composition of elementary functions (not including trig functions) meaning that $f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\zeta(x)}$ (just an example) does not hold!

Is there a known function that solves this?

Comment: You probably want to exclude constant functions as well.

Comment: Are $a,b$ fixed or varying?

Comment: @GhostAmarth Yes, correct otherwise an easy function would solve this ;-)

Comment: If constants are in, then $\;f(x)=\pi\;$ makes the trick, with $\;a=0,\,b=1\;$

Comment: I added the condition that $f$ cannot have any irrational variables as constants inside otherwise there are infinite functions that satisfy this question, thanks for noticing

Comment: @cosmo5 I am not sure if to say yes or no, so for now we'll say they are fixed constants (rational)

Comment: This question is too open-ended. Saying "all other functions are welcome" is too vague. Is the $\Gamma$ function permitted?

Comment: @RobArthan If you consider $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$ then yes, but not the integral as it contain an infinite value (integral)

Comment: I think you should either (1) rephrase this as a "fun" question with no attempt at a rigorous  definition of what you are looking for, but asking for aesthetically pleasing solutions; or (2) come up with a precise statement: is there a function $f$ in the closure of such-and-such a set of functions (e.g., the smallest set of functions containing polynomials with rational coefficients and $\exp$ and closed under composition).

Comment: @RobArthan I added a paragraph dealing with the 'vagueness' of the restrictions on $f$ Thank you!

Comment: And thank you! I hope you get some interesting suggestions. I will certainly try to think of one.